# Did Skyler have genuine feelings for Ted Beneke?

Tags: character, breaking-bad

In the series *Breaking Bad*, I couldn't quite figure this one out completely while observing Skyler and her affair with Ted Beneke. So, did she really have any genuine feelings for Ted or was it plain revenge on Walter?

Comment: It's never really discussed or shown whether the feelings were genuine or if she was just looking for a diversion/revenge.  She knew Ted had feelings for her, so it may have just been a case of Ted being an easy target for her attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skyler most likely did not have genuine feelings for Ted, as their past affair was not something Tyler wanted to talk about when Marie mentioned it. It was done as an act of revolt against Walter and as an attempt to get back at him by demonstrating independence.

Answer (score 2):

I think it was just revenge on Walt, she left Ted years ago. Also, She helped him with the money because she was involved in the cooking of the books.

That's my opinion so, It may be wrong.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, she never "left" Ted.  They never dated or had any intimate relationship prior to the affair.

Comment: I understood that she left Ted after having a relationship with Walt and marrying him.

Comment: The Whites met when Walter was working in Los Alamos National Laboratory, Skyler in a restaurant near the lab. It was implied that Beneke Fabricators was her last employment before becoming a stay-at-home mum as of the start of S01E01.